# Search Active Directory

Tags: windows-xp, active-directory, address-book

How can I search the active directory and get more than 100 results using the Address Book?

Currently, if I search for "m", I get a message informing me that "there are too many entries in the directory service..."

Comment: How are you currently searching AD? Through a script? Through the Admin tool? Some other way?

Comment: @EBGreen Through the address book.

Start>All Programs>Accessories>Address Book>Find People>Look in:Active Directory.

Comment: Not sure where that comes from actually. I have office including Outlook installed but I don't have that app. Do you know where it came from?

Comment: @EBGreen Address Book comes with [Windows XP](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/app_wab.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 0):

[image: My AD is configured to allow a max search of 10,000 objects]

**This link will provide you with your answer only if you use AD User & Computer instead of Address Book.** I will add the steps in my message for your convenience.

```
Start the MMC Active Directory Users and Computers snap-in.
Right-click the container, and select Properties.
Select the Group Policy tab.
Select the Group Policy Object, and select Edit.
Select the User Configuration branch, and expand Administrative Templates > Desktop > Active Directory.
Double-click Maximum size of Active Directory searches.
Select Enabled, and set the number (e.g., 20000).
Click Apply.
Click OK.
Close the Group Policy Editor.
To edit the registry to set the number for a user:

Start regedit.
Go to the
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft

registry entry.

From the Edit menu, select New > Key.
Enter
​Windows

Select the new Windows key, and from the Edit menu, select New, Key.
Enter
​Directory UI
Go to the Directory UI key, and from the Edit menu, select New, DWORD Value.
Enter
​QueryLimit
and press Enter.

Double-click the new value, and set the decimal value (i.e. 20000).
Click OK.
Close the registry editor.
For both methods, the change will take effect when the user logs on the next time.
```

Source: [https://petri.com/active_directory_search_limit/#:~:text=Select%20the%20User%20Configuration%20branch,Click%20Apply](https://petri.com/active_directory_search_limit/#:%7E:text=Select%20the%20User%20Configuration%20branch,Click%20Apply).